# Копирование шаблона bitrix компонента (списка новостей) в режиме правки. Перекрытие меню

Tags: битрикс, cms, компоненты, копирование

Есть компонент - список новостей (действую согласно [Курс по битрикс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcT4OfTsanQ&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=14&t=488s))

```html
                <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                    "bitrix:news.list",
                    "",
                    Array(
                        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
                        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
                        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
                        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
                        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
                        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
                        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
                        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
                        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
                        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "N",
                        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
                        "FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
                        "FILTER_NAME" => "",
                        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
                        "IBLOCK_ID" => "4",
                        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "other",
                        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
                        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
                        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
                        "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
                        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
                        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
                        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
                        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
                        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
                        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
                        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
                        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
                        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
                        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
                        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("URL",""),
                        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
                        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
                        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "N",
                        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N",
                        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
                        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
                        "SHOW_404" => "N",
                        "SORT_BY1" => "SORT",
                        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
                        "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
                        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
                        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N"
                    )
                );?>
```

Открываю страницу в режиме правки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно меню обращения к компоненту перекрылось и я не могу скопировать шаблон компонента.

1. Как получить доступ к меню и скопировать шаблон компонента?
2. Как я понимаю шаблон компонента можно скопировать вручную. Но я не знаю по какому пути надо копировать и куда вставлять (нужные **точные пути**). Если знаете, то подскажите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно я скопировал шаблон `.default` компонента `news.list` из папки `/bitrix/components/bitrix/news.list/templates` в папку `/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/slider_index` (скопированный компонент получил имя `slider_index`), но это не помогло.
Прилагаю код главной страницы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?></title>
    <?$APPLICATION->ShowHead();?>

    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/screen.css");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/font/font.css");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/jquery.fancybox.css");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/jquery.bxslider.css");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/jquery.formstyler.css");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/jquery.formstyler.theme.css");?>

    <?$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/jquery.formstyler.min.js");?>
    <?$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/main.js");?>
    <?$isIndex = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage() == SITE_DIR; ?>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel"><?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?></div>
    <header>
        <?echo $isIndex;?>
        <div class="top_head_white_bl">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="top_head_logo">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:main.include",
                        "",
                        Array(
                            "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
                            "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc",
                            "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "",
                            "PATH" => "/include/inc_logo.php"
                        )
                    );?>
                </div>
                <div class="header_menu_bl">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "header", Array(
                        "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",    // Разрешить несколько активных пунктов одновременно
                            "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",    // Тип меню для остальных уровней
                            "DELAY" => "N", // Откладывать выполнение шаблона меню
                            "MAX_LEVEL" => "3", // Уровень вложенности меню
                            "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "",    // Значимые переменные запроса
                            "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",    // Время кеширования (сек.)
                            "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A",   // Тип кеширования
                            "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
                            "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",  // Тип меню для первого уровня
                            "USE_EXT" => "Y",   // Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php
                            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "horizontal_multilevel"
                        ),
                        false
                    );?>
                </div>
                <div class="top_head_favor_bl">
                    <div class="top_head_favor">
                        <a href="">Избранное</a><span>10</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="top_head_bt">
                    <a class="gray_bt" data-fancybox data-src="#call_back" href="javascript:;">
                        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                            "bitrix:main.include",
                            "",
                            Array(
                                "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
                                "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc",
                                "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "",
                                "PATH" => "/include/inc_callback.php"
                            )
                        );?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?echo $isIndex;?>
        <?if($isIndex):?>
        <div class="index_slider_bl">
            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:news.list",
                "",
                Array(
                    "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
                    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
                    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
                    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
                    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
                    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
                    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
                    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
                    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
                    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
                    "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
                    "DETAIL_URL" => "",
                    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
                    "DISPLAY_DATE" => "N",
                    "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
                    "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
                    "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
                    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
                    "FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
                    "FILTER_NAME" => "",
                    "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
                    "IBLOCK_ID" => "4",
                    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "other",
                    "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
                    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
                    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
                    "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
                    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
                    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
                    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
                    "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
                    "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
                    "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
                    "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("URL",""),
                    "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
                    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
                    "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "N",
                    "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N",
                    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
                    "SET_TITLE" => "N",
                    "SHOW_404" => "N",
                    "SORT_BY1" => "SORT",
                    "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
                    "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
                    "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
                    "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N"
                )
            );?>
            <ul class="index_slider">
                <li>
                    <div class="index_slider_el" style="background-image:url(<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/index_slider_bg.png);">
                        <div class="standart_width index_slider_cont">
                            <div class="ind_slid_txt_bl">
                                <div class="ind_slid_tit">Современный монстр.</div>
                                <div class="ind_slid_txt">В своем стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что синтетическое тестирование требует анализа форм воздействия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также социально-экономическое развитие создает предпосылки для как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений!</div>
                                <a class="blue_bt" href="">Узнать подробнее</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ind_slid_img"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/index_slider1.png" alt=""/></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="index_slider_el" style="background-image:url(<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/index_slider_bg.png);">
                        <div class="standart_width index_slider_cont">
                            <div class="ind_slid_txt_bl">
                                <div class="ind_slid_tit">Осенний ценопад</div>
                                <div class="ind_slid_txt">Перспективное планирование способствует повышению качества поставленных обществом задач. В частности, синтетическое тестирование прекрасно подходит для реализации стандартных подходов.</div>
                                <a class="blue_bt" href="">Узнать подробнее</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ind_slid_img"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/index_slider1.png" alt=""/></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="gray_head_info_bl">
            <div class="standart_width clear_after">
                <div class="mouse_bl"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/mouse.png" alt=""/></div>
                <div class="head_search_bl">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск товаров и услуг"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="найти"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?endif?>
    </header>
        <?if(!$isIndex):?>
            <section>
                <div class="bread_crumbs_bl">
                    <div class="standart_width">
                        <ul class="bread_crumbs not_style">
                            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:breadcrumb", "navchain", Array(
                                "PATH" => "",   // Путь, для которого будет построена навигационная цепочка (по умолчанию, текущий путь)
                                    "SITE_ID" => "s1",  // Cайт (устанавливается в случае многосайтовой версии, когда DOCUMENT_ROOT у сайтов разный)
                                    "START_FROM" => "0",    // Номер пункта, начиная с которого будет построена навигационная цепочка
                                ),
                                false
                            );?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?endif;?>
```

Резервная копия - https://transfiles.ru/8gw4h.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать название своего шаблона:

```
            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:news.list",
                "slider_index",
 ...
```

Comment: после добавления имени шаблона возникла проблема на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489226/Покосившаяся-верстка.

Comment: см. также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489879/Пути-для-копирования-шаблона-компонента-news-list